# Flutter: Binding CustomPainter with ScrollController

Tags: flutter, animation, scrollcontroller

I have a `CustomPainter` like below and I want it to bind with a parent widget containing a `ListView.builder` how do I do that?
**Expected Behaviour:** the painter should paint as I scroll up or down.

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PlayerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Animation<double> animation;
  final Paint backgroundPaint;
  final Color bgColor;
  final Color thumbColor;
  final Paint sliderPaint;
  final Paint thumbPaint;

  PlayerPainter({this.animation, this.bgColor, this.thumbColor})
      : backgroundPaint = Paint()..color = bgColor,
        sliderPaint = Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeWidth = 3.0,
        thumbPaint = Paint()..color = thumbColor,
        super(repaint: animation);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final value = animation.value;
    final radius = size.width * 0.5;
    final thumbRadius = 4.0;
    final rect = Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(radius, size.height), radius: radius);
    final thumbPosX = radius + (radius * -cos(value * pi));
    final thumbPosY = (size.height - thumbRadius) + ((size.height - thumbRadius) * -sin(value * pi));
    sliderPaint.shader = LinearGradient(colors: [
      const Color(0xFFCC2B5E),
      const Color(0xFF753A88),
      const Color(0xFFCC2B5E),
      const Color(0xFF753A88),
    ]).createShader(rect);

    canvas.drawArc(rect, pi, pi, false, backgroundPaint);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, pi, value * pi, false, sliderPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(thumbPosX, thumbPosY), thumbRadius, thumbPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(PlayerPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

parent.dart

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _controller = AnimationController(
          value: _scrollController.offset,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 0),
          vsync: this,
        );
      });
    });
}
PlayerView(
...
  controller: _controller,
  ),
```

> ════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> _MusicScreenState is a SingleTickerProviderStateMixin but multiple tickers were created.

Comment: check `ScrollController` - it is `Listenable` so it can be passed to a `CustomPainter` as a `repaint` named parameter (`super(repaint: controller)`)

Comment: @pskink but how Do I pass in the value as well for `Animation<double>`?

Comment: pass both `Listenable`s and use `Listenable.merge` in `super(...)` - something like `Listenable.merge([l0, l1])`

Comment: This means that I have to create `Animation<double>` but what I want is that the `animation` should be controlled by the `ScrollController` only.

Comment: so don't need that animation if it is the same as current scroll position of your listview

Comment: But I need that `animation` inside the `void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) `

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/nwv1pRtw

Comment: @pskink ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views

Comment: so attach it to only one - single `ScrollController` cannot control multiple views

Comment: I am only using a single `ScrollController`

Comment: i gave you a sample, working code in the top comment - just use it

Comment: now I am getting null point exception on the `ctrl.offset`

Comment: `class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
final controller = ScrollController();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CustomPaint(
painter: MyPainter(controller),
child: ListView(
controller: controller,
children: [
for(var i = 0; i < 64; i++)
Text(' === item #$i', textScaleFactor: 2)
],
),
);
}
}`

Comment: Still the same ```The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toDouble()```

Comment: there is no `toDouble` method called in my code

Comment: I am using `controller.position.pixels` It is showing at that

Comment: there is no no need for it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart#L118 `double get offset => position.pixels;` just use `ctrl.offset / 10` as i did

Comment: But I am also using `controller.position.pixels  / controller.position.maxScrollExtent` and It is also throwing NPE

Comment: `@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var cur = ctrl.offset;
    var max = ctrl.position.maxScrollExtent;
    print('0 <= $cur <= $max');
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, ctrl.offset / 10, 100, 100), Paint()..color = Colors.orange);
  }` works just fine